# Open a local file in Colabrotory Python Jupyter Notebook on a Chromebook

Tags: python, google-chrome, jupyter-notebook, filenames

As the title suggests, I am working in a Jupyter Notebook, using Google's Colaborotory.  I want to open a local file (meaning actually stored on my machine, not somewhere in cloudland) using IPython.  I have tried a number of formats for the file name, but have not hit upon a format that does not result in the error, e.g.

```
[Errno 2] No such file or directory: file:///media/removable/HamRadio/COS/AI/mnist_test_10.csv
```

I have searched around but haven't found any reference work that specifies how to accomplish this.  Any direction is appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

You need to upload your file to Google Colab first then you right-click on file and choose copy file path

[image]